# Python 3 Scapy packet: I need to compute md5

Tags: python, md5, scapy

I am writing a Python script computing an authenticator field of radius accounting protocol (RFC 2866).

I have a Scapy packet already:

```
Packet=IP(dst=host)/UDP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port)/RadiusPacket/(avp)
```

I can hexdump it using hexdump(Packet):

```
0000   45 00 00 4C 00 01 00 00  40 11 1F FB AC 1C 01 65   E..L....@......e
0010   AC 1E 01 06 EE 88 07 15  00 38 79 47 04 FE 00 30   .........8yG...0
0020   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   0000000000000000
0030   01 06 74 65 73 74 04 06  AC 1C 01 65 2C 0A 30 31   ..test.....e,.01
0040   30 32 30 33 30 34 28 06  00 00 00 01               020304(.....
```

I need to compute the md5 of octets starting at byte 25 (till the end of the packet).

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: `hashlib.md5(raw(p)[25:])` ?

Comment: Thanks Grant, this is exactly what i needed;)